# How to get Windows system calls assembly statically?

Tags: windows, assembly, dll, kernel

I am trying to find a specific pattern in the Windows system calls, for research purposes.

So far i've been looking into the Windows dlls such as `ntdll.dll, user32.dll`, etc., but those seem to contain only wrapper codes for preparing to jump to the system call. For example:

```
mov     eax, 101Eh
lea     edx, [esp+arg_0]
mov     ecx, 0
call    large dword ptr fs:0C0h
retn    10h
```

I'm guessing the `call large dword ptr fs:0C0h` instruction is another gateway in the chain that finally leads to the actual assembly, but I was wondering if I can get to that assembly directly.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see what is at `fs:0ch` and then disassembling that function?

Comment: this is wow process (you use 64bit windows). this code enter to x64 gate. you can do this say under WinDbg. on another side - already 64bit code - `CpupReturnFromSimulatedCode`. can read for example - http://waleedassar.blogspot.com/2012/07/wow64-user-mode-system-calls-hooking.html

Comment: @RbMm Thanks that's really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong `dll`s. The system calls are in `ntoskrnl.exe`.

If you look at `NtOpenFile()` in `ntoskrnl.exe` you'll see:

```
mov     r11, rsp
sub     rsp, 88h
mov     eax, [rsp+88h+arg_28]
xor     r10d, r10d
mov     [r11-10h], r10
mov     [rsp+88h+var_18], 20h ; int
mov     [r11-20h], r10d
mov     [r11-28h], r10
mov     [r11-30h], r10d
mov     [r11-38h], r10d
mov     [r11-40h], r10
mov     [rsp+88h+var_48], eax ; int
mov     eax, [rsp+88h+arg_20]
mov     [rsp+88h+var_50], 1 ; int
mov     [rsp+88h+var_58], eax ; int
mov     [r11-60h], r10d
mov     [r11-68h], r10
call    IopCreateFile
add     rsp, 88h
retn
```

Which is the true body of the function. Most of the work is done in `IopCreateFile()`, but you can follow it statically and do whatever analysis you need.

Comment: While most of the I/O Manager's work is in [`IoCreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548418), most of the work in creating or opening a device or file is in the [`IRP_MJ_CREATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548630) routine of the driver and filter drivers in the device stack. But this may be irrelevant to the OP's research.